# java.lang.IllegalStateException: open with mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am following a tutorial on using mongo DB with spring.
i have the following code:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");
MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
ctx.close(); /* closing the application context was my addition and wan't in the tutorial code*/
// ... some operations ...//

  }

}
```

and following spring configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

when i tried following this code example, i got the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
```

After a bit of searching i found the reason behind the exception in this [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1311)

Quote:
There's a simple reason why the Spring Data app is getting this exception. When you close the ApplicationContext in SpringApp.main, it shuts down all the beans, which in turn closes the MongoClient, which results in the IllegalStateException when the background thread tries to use that MongoClient. If you remove that call to close the ApplicationContext, the Spring Data example doesn't throw an exception either.

I removed the context.close(); part, and it worked.

so my question is: does it makes sense to leave the application context open?
My intention is to create a Restful service that will receive objects and store them in a mongo collection, so am i supposed to just create the applciationCotnext and leave it open?